# This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted on setting Proxy in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest

I am trying to use proxy after getting the response for getting a response to the second time by proxy. Here is my code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(@"206.189.118.178", 8080) { BypassProxyOnLocal = false };
        request.Proxy = myproxy;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        var responseByProxy = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But I am getting this exception on line: `request.Proxy = myproxy` :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted.'
> How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Make the changes **before** any calls to `GetResponse`. I suspect you forgot to comment out the second line of code. If you didn't, spin up a _second_ request rather than reusing the first one.

Comment: @mjwills I want to GetResponse twice. With proxy and without proxy. I could create a new request when  it is impossible to use the first request for the second time

Comment: `I could create a new request when it is impossible to use the first request for the second time` Perfect. Do that.